# Find the minimum value of $\frac{(a^2+a+1)(b^2+b+1)(c^2+c+1)}{abc}$ if $a,b,c$ are positive integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't see any rigorous method. I did it by trial and error. For $0$, it would be undefined. For $1$, the answer comes $27$. 
Also, if we see the numerator, when we multiply all the $3$ terms, there would be a $abc$ and $a^2b^2c^2$ term. Which tells that numerator will increase faster than the denominator. We have to minimize the numerator and at the same time maximise the denominator. But by the earlier observation, it seems that $27$ is the answer. 
Is it right? Or is there a rigorous method also? 
*Please don't use any complex theorems, only algebra.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For real $a>0$

$$\dfrac{a^2+a+1}a=\left(\sqrt a-\dfrac1{\sqrt a}\right)^2+3\ge3$$

the equality occurs if $\sqrt a-\dfrac1{\sqrt a}=0\iff a=1$ which is fortunately a positive integer.

Comment: Okay, understood! So by multiplying all $3$, we get $27$!

Comment: As an aside, $\sqrt x-\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\simeq\ln x$, for $x\simeq1$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\frac{x^2+x+1}{x}=x+\frac{1}{x}+1$.

We need to show that if $x$ is positive then $x+\frac{1}{x}\ge 2$. (The value $2$ is taken on at $x=1$). We have 
$$x+\frac{1}{x}-2=\frac{(x-1)^2}{x}\ge 0.$$

Comment: Close to @labbhattacharjee's post. Gonna accept that.

Comment: Yes, both use any square is $\ge 0$.

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you so much but (y)!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f(n)=\frac{n^2+n+1}{n}$ is increasing with $n$ in the positive integers AND that $f(1)>1$. Hence $f(a)f(b)f(c)\geq f(1)f(1)f(1)=27$